# Facebook and Office suite preinstalled on new Gingerbread device?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, bloatware

I just bought a Gingerbread phone and I was surprised to find Facebook and Office Suite already installed.

Do these apps come preinstalled on Gingerbread as on my previous android which was a older OS I had to download these apps. I did buy a new phone and I am just suspicious in case it isn't new!?

<sup>I apologize if this seems a stupid question.</sup>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This depends on

1. the manufacturer of the device
2. the provider where you bought your device.

The manufacturer pre-installs some applications. Also the provider may pre-install some applications.

So this does not depend on the Android version but on the manufacturer and/or provider.

Answer (score 1):

Many Android phones come packed with useless software preinstalled by the device’s manufacturer and your cellular carrier, this is called "bloatware".

Software vendors usually pay to pre-install lite versions of their products on the new devices to promote their work.

On the other hand, it may happen that apps already installed are useful and selected based on usage statistics.

---

There's no bulletproof method to ascertain if the device as been used before, but the physical appearance,  the protective plastic on the Glass and Camera, the packing, etc... all should give you a concrete idea about the device usage.